# IBM Appscan vs Flaw finder

Tags: vulnerability

What is the main difference between an open source tool like flaw finder and a costly commercial tool like IBM Appscan. One is reporting that we get a presentable report with commericial tools but is there any difference of techniques in code reviewing?? Does IBM appscan use any other techniques other than used by flaw finder (one is text matching), on the basis of which we can say that ibm appscan is better than flawfinder??